# Calculate the biggest word size in bytes of submitted content

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the largest word size in byte for Unicode content in javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by a word? In the grammatical sense presumably? Is up-to-date three words or one?

Comment: Single word in the sentence. for e.g. 'Hi this is good.' here 'Hi', 'this', 'is' and 'good' are separate words.

Comment: How important is the *Unicode* part? Do you really need all characters, or can you handle just a few European ones?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function largestWord(str) {
  var words = encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\%]/," ").split("%20"); // we cannot remove the dots since \W kills all foreign chars too
  alert(words);
  var longest = "";
  for (var i=0, n=words.length;i<n;i++) {
    var test = words[i].replace("%2C",""); // we need to get rid of dots and other punktuation here
    alert(test +':'+longest)
    if (test.length > longest.length) longest=test;
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(longest)  
}

document.write(largestWord('Duh disti dusti du dist du Børk, Bårker, Bærkest'));
```

Comment: or return longest.length or return decodeURIComponent(longest).length

Comment: Better now? Note the function still needs to handle other punktuation

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxLength = 0;
s.replace(/\w+/g, function(g0){ maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, g0.length);});
```

This is slightly abusive, but effective. Here, we're using the callback of `replace` to iterate over the matched words (here, alphanumeric and underscores, but you can change that), and check the length of every matched word against our current maximal length.

Comment: Nice idea, but try it on 

var str = "Duh disti dusti du dist du Børk, Bårker, Bærkest";

Comment: @mplungjan - it fails, but you only need to change `\w` to make it work. JavaScript doesn't support unicode. If you want full unicode support your best bet may be a library, like http://xregexp.com/plugins/ . Using `encodeURIComponent` is a clever hack, but it also fail on all special characters (try `@` for one, or any other unicode non-alphabetic character) - Sadly, you can't get around it if you want real support `:)`